# Using Module Npp on C:\Python27

Tags: python, plugins, notepad++

I use Notepad++ (and the plugins) as IDE for coding. I downloaded a plugin named "Python Script" and this plugin uses a very useful module for write Notepad++ commands (Npp module).

Now i want to use the Npp module on offical version of python2.7. I downloaded Python Script for Notepad++, and Npp modules works fine with it. But, if i want to code something outside the Plugin, an error occurs ( Import Error: No module named Npp ). There is a way to import Npp module to my official python version?

Comment: NPP module probably require Notepad++, so can't be used alone.